# How to optimize accuracy code for multiple predictive models in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I made a cross validation function which does it for several models.

I have a function with the models I want to calculate, and in the cross validation I call it so I get a data frame called `results` with the Class or Labels, against each prediction for each iteration:

```
 head(results)
     iteration class ksvm rf
65          1     4    4  4
306         1     2    2  2
300         1     4    4  4
385         1     2    2  2
431         1     2    2  2
205         1     4    4  4
```

(The index can be ignored, since it comes from the data being sampled).

Since I have a 5-fold cross validation, I have 5 iterations predicting in this case `ksvm` and `rf`. (These are stored in a variable called `algorithms`.

After this I am calculating the accuracy this way:

```
   results %>% 
     group_by(iteration) %>% 
     summarise(acc_ksvm = sum(ksvm == class) / n() , acc_rf = sum(rf == class) / n() )
```

Output:

```
   iteration  acc_ksvm    acc_rf
      (int)     (dbl)     (dbl)
 1         1 0.9603175 0.9603175
 2         2 0.9760000 0.9680000
 3         3 0.9603175 0.9523810
 4         4 0.9840000 0.9920000
 5         5 0.9444444 0.9523810
```

**Question:** 
Is there a way to optimize it? I will eventually increase the models, I just want to pass `algorithms` variable in a function, and calculate the accuracy for all the models without manually  writing `summarise(acc_ksvm = sum(ksvm == class) / n() , acc_rf = sum(rf == class) / n() )` for each model.

Can this be done with an apply? Or do I have to change the way my `df`is built in order to also group by model?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you looking to optimize? Speed? This seems to be a fairly elegant solution thus far. If all you're looking to do is add models to the `algorithms` vector, I think the `dplyr` code you have above does pretty well, assuming your data aren't *huge* and you aren't testing many parameters for many models.

Comment: You are right, maybe I should have wrote *Automate* instead of *Optimize*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sum(ksvm == class) / n()` is really the group average of the algorithm column's `TRUE` matches to *class*, consider creating the logical value columns (`TRUE/FALSE` matches) first and then use dplyr's `summarise_each` across all other columns:

```
algorithms <- c("alg1", "alg2", "alg3", "alg4", "alg5")

results[algorithms] <- sapply(algorithms, function(i){
  results[i] == results$class
})

summarydf <-
  results[c("iteration", algorithms)] %>% 
  group_by(iteration) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>%
  setNames(c("iteration", paste0("acc_", algorithms)))
```

Comment: This is really interesting, I appreciate it!